# Un Array de Float convertirlos a Array de Int en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, parsear

Tengo este Array de números flotante:

datos = [0.1, 2.3, 5.6, 7.8, 10.9]

Solicitan que estos números sean enteros, también quieren que se conserven los valores originales.

¿Qué método de matriz le recomendaría que utilice para crear la matriz de enteros?

Entiendo que seria crear un nuevo Array a partir de "datos", pero este debe representar los valores en enteros.

Comment: No me funciono undefined

Comment: perdón, eso no crea un nuevo array. para eso usa `.map`, así `datos = datos.map(num=>parseInt(num)); console.log(datos)`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, cree una nueva variable con array para conservar los datos de la primera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el metodo .map, aplicaremos una función a cada uno de los items del array principal devolviendo un array con los nuevos valores, sin modificar el antiguo:

```
const datos = [0.1, 2.3, 5.6, 7.8, 10.9];
const datosInt = datos.map((item) => parseInt(item));
```